# Elasticsearch foselastica repository and groupBy

Tags: symfony, elasticsearch, elastica, foselasticabundle

Hello I have a problem..

I have my elastica repository

```
namespace XX\xxx;

use FOS\ElasticaBundle\Repository;

class TestRepository extends Repository
{
public function getExamples($argOne, $argTwo) {
    $query = new BoolQuery();

    $matchOne = new Match();
    $matchOne->setField('column_one', $argOne);
    $query->addMust($matchOne);

    $matchTwo = new Match();
    $matchOne->setField('column_two', $argTwo);
    $query->addMust($matchTwo);

    return $this->find($query);
  }
}
```

And mapping

```
...
types:
   example:
      mappings:
         column_one:
              type: integer
         column_two:
              type: string
         column_three:
              type: date
```

My problem is..

I need to get query group by column three. And I have no idea how to do this.

I'll be grateful for the informations..

Answer (score 5):

You need to use `Aggregations`.

Example:

```
use Elastica\Aggregation\Terms;
use Elastica\Query;

// set up the aggregation
$termsAgg = new Terms("dates");
$termsAgg->setField("column_three");
$termsAgg->setSize(10);

// add the aggregation to a Query object
$query = new Query();
$query->addAggregation($termsAgg);

$index = $elasticaClient->getIndex('someindex');
$buckets = $index->search($query)->getAggregation("dates");

foreach($buckets as $bucket){
    $statsAggResult = $bucket["column_three"];
    // do something with the result of the stats agg
}
```

Read more here: http://elastica.io/example/aggregations/terms.html

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but here's problem.

How to read this data?
I search about this and i found methos search(). It return SetResults with method getAggregations().

But.. this is repository.. there is method find() returns array...

How get I aggregations in this case?

Comment: i added example with looping through data buckets

Comment: ResultSet is iterable so you can just loop through it.

Answer (score 0):

**Terms Aggregation**

From https://elastica.io/example/aggregations/terms.html

```
use Elastica\Aggregation\Terms;
use Elastica\Aggregation\Stats;
use Elastica\Query;

$termsAgg = new Terms("genders");
$termsAgg->setField("gender");
$termsAgg->setOrder("height_stats.avg", "desc");

$statsAgg = new Stats("height_stats");
$statsAgg->setField("height");

$termsAgg->addAggregation($statsAgg);

$index = $elasticaClient->getIndex('someindex');
$buckets = $index->search($query)->getAggregation("genders");

foreach($buckets as $bucket){
    $statsAggResult = $bucket["height_stats"];
    // do something with the result of the stats agg
}
```